# cancel package: combine bcancel and cancelto (bcancelto?)

Tags: cancel

Is there a way to create a negative slope with the `cancel` package, but using `\cancelto`? i.e. I would like to combine the two commands so that I have a negative slope but with an arrow and number.

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{journal}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\[
\cancelto{0}{X^2}
\]
\[
\bcancel{X^2}
\]
%$\bcancelto{0}{X^2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is what you are after:

[image: cancelto lower right example]

This was achieved by first patching the `\canto@vector` command to change modify the script placement based on the sign of the y component of the vector (given by `#4`). Then, `\@cancelto` was renewed with an optional parameter. If blank, the standard behavior would be achieved. If a `-` is passed, then the vector is pointed downward. Finally, the `\bcancelto` command was created, assuming the default `smaller` option is used (`Smaller` or `samesize` would require an alternative definition to modify the script size used).

Your modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter

    %patch \canto@vector to correctly place script.
    \pretocmd{\canto@vector}{\edef\testneg{#4<0}}{}{\@latex@error{Patch fail}}
    \patchcmd{\canto@vector}{^}{\ifnum\testneg_\else^\fi}{}{\@latex@error{Patch fail}}
    \patchcmd{\canto@vector}{\raise#2\dimen@}{\raise\dimexpr\ifnum\testneg-\ht\z@+\fi#2\dimen@}{}{\@latex@error{Patch fail}}

    \renewcommand\@cancelto[5][]{%
        \OriginalPictureCmds\@begin@tempboxa\hbox{\m@th$#4{#5}$}%
        \dimen@\width % wide
        \@min@pt\dimen@ 2\@min@pt\totalheight4
        \ifdim\totalheight<\dimen@
         \@tempcnta\totalheight \multiply\@tempcnta 5 \divide\@tempcnta\dimen@
         \@tempdimb 3\p@ % extra width for arrowhead ("+2")
         \advance\dimen@ \ifcase\@tempcnta 5\or 5\or 4\or 3\else 2\fi \p@
         \@min@pt\dimen@9\advance\dimen@\p@ 
         \edef\@tempa{\ifcase\@tempcnta 544{#1 1}\or 544{#1 1}\or 542{#1 1}\or 444{#1 3}\else 361{#1 1}\fi
              {\strip@pt\dimen@}{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}}%
         \def\@tempb{Cancel #4 to #2; case wide }%
        \else % tall
         \advance\totalheight3\p@ % "+2"
         \@tempcnta\dimen@ \multiply\@tempcnta 5 \divide\@tempcnta\totalheight
         \advance\totalheight3\p@ % "+2"
         \dimen@ \ifcase\@tempcnta .25\or .25\or .5\or .75\else 1\fi \totalheight
         \@tempdimb \ifcase\@tempcnta .8\or .8\or 1.2\or 1.5\else 2\fi \p@
         \edef\@tempa{\ifcase\@tempcnta 081{#1 4}\or 081{#1 4}\or 181{#1 2}\or 273{#1 4}\else 361{#1 1}\fi
              {\strip@pt\dimen@}{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}}%
        \fi
        \dimen@\height
        \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{$\m@th\vcenter{\box\@tempboxa}$}%
        \advance\dimen@-\height % the difference in height
        \unitlength\p@ \canc@thinlines
        {\/\raise\dimen@\hbox{\expandafter\canto@vector\@tempa{#2}{#3}}}%
        \@end@tempboxa
    }

    \def\bcancelto#1#2{\mathchoice    %  smaller option (default)
      {\@cancelto[-]\textstyle{#1}\displaystyle{#2}}%
      {\@cancelto[-]\scriptstyle{#1}\textstyle{#2}}%
      {\@cancelto[-]\scriptscriptstyle{#1}\scriptstyle{#2}}%
      {\@cancelto[-]\scriptscriptstyle{#1}\scriptscriptstyle{#2}}%
      }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\cancelto{0}{X^2}
\]
\[
\bcancel{X^2}
\]
\[
\bcancelto{0}{X^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

As a note, I'd recommend using the `makeroom` option to accommodate the arrow head for the `\bcancelto`.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I get this error: ``Undefined control sequence. \@begin@tempboxa \hbox {\m@th... \cancelto{0}{X^2}``. What is it?

Comment: @yoki: Without knowing more, it is impossible to say what is going on. Maybe you could post a new question with a MWE (or, in this case, not working example)?